# How to see Saturn's rings through a pair of binoculars?

Tags: amateur-observing, saturn

I have a pair of 15x70 binoculars. I would not say what manufacturer to avoid being the subject of 'hold'.

The current angular diameter is 15.5 arcseconds. I am wondering if that condition is enough to be able to see rings. My eyesight is fair.

Comment: [Related question.](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/8307/can-jupiters-bands-be-made-out-using-a-15x70-pair-of-binoculars)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will not be able to see Saturn's rings directly with a 15x70 telescope, but you will be able to notice that Saturn appears **elliptical, not round**. This is due to the shape of the rings around the planet, but you will not be able to resolve the hole between the rings and the planet (much less the Cassini gap).

Just as an **impractical suggestion** in the interest of giving to you a more complete answer, you *might* be able to mount a camera and use [image stacking](http://www.instructables.com/id/Astrophotography-Star-Photo-Stacking/) to see a smidge of ring and differentiate it from the sphere of the planet. If you do go this route, **please** post online about your setup and results, whether it succeeds or not.